# ¿Cómo cambiar color del texo del titulo popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentado cambar el color del texto del titulo del popover utilizando este metodo dentro del javascript

```
$(this).append('<span class="badge badge-pill label-call" style="font-size: 12px;color:white;" tabindex="0" data-trigger="focus"  data-toggle="popover"  title="" data-content="">' + count + '</span>');
```

Lo que hago en el primero es agregar el span con el atributo popover
en el segundo busco ese mismo span para poder cambiarle el color del texto

Esto lo estoy haciendo dinamicamente dentro de un ciclo ya que tambien se agregan otros span pero son con valores difenetes.

lo que quiero es cuando valide que tipo de span es, es donde se va a cambiar el color del text.

Comment: No entiendo, porque no cambias el color en el append?  Ademas estas buscando la clase `popover` pero no la agregas en el atributo `class`

Comment: Porque se cambiaría el color del span y no del titulo del texto del popover